# jquery bxslider is not working with templates inside ng view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery bxslider on my first angular project. It is not working with template inside ng view. If use this one without ng view means it is working.

This is my HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="appSathya">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modest</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header ng-include='"template/header.html"'></header>
    <section ng-view></section>

    <script src="js/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript file

```
// JavaScript Document

var app = angular.module('appSathya', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // Home
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
}]); 

app.controller('menuController', function($scope){
    $scope.menus = [
        {mitem:"Home", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"About", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"Work", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"Team", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"Services", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"Features", murl:"#/link"},
        {mitem:"contact", murl:"#/link"}
    ];
});

app.directive('startslider',function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       replace: true,
       template: '<ul class="bxslider">' +
                   '<li ng-repeat="picture in pictures">' +
                     '<img ng-src="{{picture.src}}" alt="" />' +
                   '</li>' +
                  '</ul>',
       link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.ready(function() {    
               $("." + $(elm[0]).attr('class')).bxSlider({
                    mode: 'fade',
                    pager: false,
                    autoControls: true
            });

          });
      }
    };
});

app.controller('PageCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pictures = [
       {src:'img/banner.jpg' },
       {src:'img/banner.jpg' },
       {src:'img/banner.jpg' }
     ];
});
```

Comment: Create a directive - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513865/2792555

Comment: @AdamGibbons  i'll look into it and confirm to you...

Comment: Try changing the template to a templetUrl and add the HTML to a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

Change you order of **script includes** to this below:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
```

the reason that your code may malfunction angular has it's own version of jqlite and strips certain namespaces and attributes... but if you change the order angular has a function that recognize if jquery calls supercede the angular versions.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to use a jQuery plugin inside Angular, then 
the [jQuery Passthrough directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

First include JQuery before AngularJS, then in jquery code use jQuery instead of $ since angular also uses $.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing your script src links in the header? Sure, it's sometimes required to place them in the footer, but if you want them to fire before anything else, play about with the order. Looking at the code, I'd suggest placing your `<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>` tags in the head?